# JXBrowser failed to launch in Ubuntu18.04

Tags: java, ubuntu-18.04, jxbrowser

I tried to launch the application from JXBrowser in ubuntu 18.04 OS. It is giving the following error. But it is working fine with other versions of Ubuntu.

2019-02-19 21:05:20,407 [Thread-1] ERROR c.m.m.g.w.jxbrowser.JXBrowserHandler - JXBrowser failed to launch. Failed to start IPC process. com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPCException: Failed to start IPC process. at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.d.run(SourceFile:208) ~[jxbrowser-6.22.1.jar:6.22.1] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_162] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing dependendecies have been detected. Check the log for details. at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.ExternalChromiumProcessLinux.preProcessRun(SourceFile:3150) ~[jxbrowser-6.22.1.jar:6.22.1] at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.ExternalChromiumProcess.doStart(SourceFile:62) ~[jxbrowser-6.22.1.jar:6.22.1] at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.ChromiumProcess.start(SourceFile:235) ~[jxbrowser-6.22.1.jar:6.22.1] at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.d.run(SourceFile:199) ~[jxbrowser-6.22.1.jar:6.22.1] ... 1 common frames omitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JxBrowser 6.22.1 is based on Chromium 64 engine which requires some dependencies installed in the system.

The issue should be fixed after running of those commands:

```
sudo apt install libgconf2-4
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

The dependency issue on Linux is fixed in Chromium 67+ versions. We can provide you with a JxBrowser build which includes an updated Chromium engine if you contact us at customer-care@teamdev.com

Comment: It is working fine after installing the libgconf2-4 library. Thank you so much @Serhii Fedchenko.

Comment: Hi, I am facing similar kind of issue running chromium browser in red hat Linux environment. I am using version jxbrowser-linux64-6.20.  Do I have to follow the same approach to fix this ?This is the error I am getting [11:29:13 SEVERE: There are next missing dependencies: 
 browsercore64 => libgconf-2.so.4, libXss.so.1, libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0, libgtk-3.so.0, libgdk-3.so.0
 libbrowsercore64.so => libgconf-2.so.4, libXss.so.1, libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0, libgtk-3.so.0, libgdk-3.so.0
11:29:13 SEVERE: Failed to start IPC process.]

Comment: @Nithin yes, you can either install the libraries manually or upgrade your JxBrowser library to a more recent version.

Comment: @SerhiiFedchenko Doesnt work here after installing these on a docker ubuntu image.

Comment: @mmm Unfortunately, we didn't test JxBrowser with Docker so can't confirm that it should be working.

Comment: @SerhiiFedchenko it is no different than any other environment. the dependencies are not working after installing apt-get install chromium-browser either. what version of chromium was used in 6.2.1  ?

Comment: If you can get this to work on ubuntu 18 or 16 from a fresh install, i would like to know the steps please. i can't.

Comment: @mmm I suppose you mean JxBrowser 6.21. It is based on Chromium 64. This version was released 2 years ago and is a very outdated version that is no longer supported. Even JxBrowser 6.x is no longer supported. Can you please upgrade your JxBrowser library to the latest version (7.8 at the moment) and check again? JxBrowser 7.8 is based on Chromium 79 and is tested with ubuntu 18 and 16.

Comment: @SerhiiFedchenko I believe the entire API changed and so we felt it was too much work to rewrite our code to fit the new code. This is why we are still on 6.21. But we got it to work on ubuntu 18 after much work. Thanks.